# How to compare the two variances in R using the F-test (given sample sizes and variances)

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to run an F-test to compare the following samples.

Group 1 sample variance: 4.1
Group 1 sample size: 32
Group 2 sample variance: 3.7
Group 2 sample size: 37

Tail: Right
Alpha level: 0.05

I know that the correct output should be p = 0.3809, F = 1.1081. I have run the test on my calculator and some online calculators (e.g., https://www.statskingdom.com/220VarF2.html) to confirm the results.

However, when I tried to run the test on R. I got a different output. The following are the codes I used on R. I tried to create two dummy vectors with `rnorm()` before using `var.test()`.

`x <- rnorm(32, mean = 0, sd = sqrt(4.1))`
`y <- rnorm(37, mean = 0, sd = sqrt(3.7))`
`var.test(x, y, alternative = "greater")`

What's wrong with my codes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are simulating data from the distribution that you specified. When you simulate those 32 and 37 observations, it's going to be different every time, so you won't get the exact same result as your original data.

See the answer here for how to do the F-test without having the original data (just the variances and sample sizes) using the pf() function and inputting the variance ratio and degrees of freedom:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/553750/how-to-perform-f-test-in-r-for-checking-equality-of-variance-homoscedasticity-h